# Difference Between Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares (IRLS) and Sequential Quadratic Programming?

Tags: optimization, compressive-sensing, convex-optimization

Part of my work is concerned with applications in Sparse Bayesian Learning and therefore I occasionally stumble over interesting papers in the field of compressed sensing.

I recently read [Iteratively Reweighted Algorithms for Compressive Sensing by Rick Chartrand and Wotao Yin](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4518498) (Available also on [DocDroid](https://docdro.id/viQVD4d)).

The paper describes how using $ {L}_{p} $ -norms with $ p < 1 $ can be used to recover signals with fewer measurements than with the LASSO ($ {L}_{1} $ Regularization).
There is even a Wikipedia entry on [Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) (IRLS).

However, I can't wrap my head around the difference between IRLS and Sequential Quadratic Programming (SQP). Is there any difference? The papers I have found on IRLS never mention SQP..

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQP is a method for solving smooth (objective and constraint functions are at least twice differentiable) *constrained* nonlinear optimization problems.  It solves a series of quadratic programming problems to converge to a solution to the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions for the constrained optimization problem.

IRLS is a method for solving *unconstrained* minimization problems by solving a sequence of least squares problems which are obtained from the original problem by a rescaling at each iteration.